# Pushing javascript object key value to javascript object key arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm having a stupid issue, probably due to my syntax.  How can I dynamically push all keys from object `arr[j]` into object `arr[i]`?

```
var arr = [{key:["data1","data2"]},{key:"data"}];
var i = 0;
var j = 1;
for(var key in arr[i]){
     arr[i][key].push(arr[j][key]);
     // arr[i][key] is an array, arr[j[key;] is a string
}
```

Rather than brutally typing everything out (which works for me):

```
arr[i][key1].push(arr[j].key1);
arr[i][key2].push(arr[j].key2);
```

`Arr[i]` will then contain its previous information and object 2 information in the form of an array.  Basically, I'm concatenating JavaScript objects.  In the end, `arr[i]` should look like:

```
key1:[arr[i].key1Value,arr[j].key1Value]
key2:[arr[i].key2Value,arr[j].key2Value]
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you add the expected output to your question as it's not clear to me what you want to do.

Comment: @Andy put it in there.  Basically I'm just concatenating JavaScript objects into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relatively simple:

```
var arr = [{key:["data1","data2"]},{key:"data"}],
    i = 0,
    j = 1,
    target = arr[i],
    source = arr[j];

target.key.push(source.key);
```

If the source has multiple keys, try this instead:

```
var arr = [{key:["data1","data2"]},{key:"data", key1: "data1", key2: "data2"}],
    i = 0,
    j = 1,
    target = arr[i],
    source = arr[j];

for(var key in source){           // Loop over the keys in the source
    target.key.push(source[key]); // And add them to the target's `key` array.
}
```

Result:

```
[
    { key: ["data1", "data2", "data", "data1", "data2"]},
    { key: "data", key1: "data1", key2: "data2"}
]
```

Comment: Nice solution, this does it!

Comment: So, this is the output you were looking for? I'm happy to be of help! Thanks for accepting the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if I understand what you try to achieve but maybe this helps:

```
var arr = [{key:["data1","data2"]},{key:"data"}];
var target = [];

arr.forEach( function(value,index){
   target['key' + index] = value;

});
```

Output:

```
target.key0 : { key: [ 'data1' 'data2' ]}
target.key1 : { key: [ 'data' ]}
```